# Oracle query for 2 previous business day

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, oracle11g

We are using Oracle 11.
We have a table DateRanges that gives us the previous business day by doing this query:

```
SELECT START_DATE FROM DateRanges WHERE ID = 14
```

--> START_DATE is the previous business day (in the example above, START_DATE = 1/24/19

We have a table with a date column (LIQ.UPD_DT), and we need to do a LEFT JOIN between table LIQ and SEC query where LIQ.UPD_DT > the 2 previous business day.

For ex: 
Today is 1/25/19.

The previous 2 business day is 1/23/19.

How do we do this query ? 
(I need to use the (+)= for the LEFT JOIN because the application that I feed this query to doesn’t do the LEFT JOIN syntax):

```
WHERE LIQ.ID (+)= SEC.ID AND LIQ.UPD_DT (+) >= '{2 previous business day}'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In Oracle you can add and subtract days (and fractions thereof) to and from dates.  So today is sysdate including date and time so you do not care about the time then " > trunc(sysdate) - 2 " would be how you write the comparsion.

To add to what I posted earlier you will need to adjust for business days and how you do that depends on your shop.  Some shops maintain a shop calendar table with holidays, etc... but one way is using code like follows to just skip Saturday and Sunday.
- -
 select trunc(sysdate) - r
 from (select rownum r from dual connect by rownum <= 8)
 where to_char(trunc(sysdate) - r,'D') not in ('1','7')
/

### TRUNC(SYS

24-JAN-19
23-JAN-19
22-JAN-19
21-JAN-19
18-JAN-19
17-JAN-19

6 rows selected. -- Notice the 19th and 20th not in list and a calculation like this would replace the hardcoded 2 days above.